# Spreadsheet fails to export to Access database when folder is not empty

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to export a spreadsheet to an Access database. I have three routines: one which creates an Access file with today's date, one which creates a connection with the database and another which imports the data to the Access file.

Everything works correctly when the folder of the dashboard is empty beforehand. However, when there is already another Access file in the folder, it does not export, displaying the following error message:

[image]

I couldn't find anything online which was relevant to this particular issue. Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
'creates an Access database
Sub CreateAccessDB()

    Dim fso
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'the path to create the new access database
    Dim strPath As String
    
    'an Access object
    Dim objAccess As Object

    date1 = Format(Date, "DD")
    
    Year = Format(Date, "YYYY")
    
    Month = Format(Date, "MM")

    MonthChar = MonthName(Month, False)

    'states the directory for our database
    strPath = "Z:\Danny Tool Test Folder\Database\" & Year & "\" & _
    Month & ". " & MonthChar & " " & Year & "\WeeklyActivity_" & date1 & Month & Year

    'if the file already exists, we open it
    If fso.FileExists(strPath & ".accdb") Then
        Call OpenAccessDatabase(strPath & ".accdb")

    'if the file does not exist, we create it
    Else

        Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
        Call objAccess.NewCurrentDatabase(strPath)
        objAccess.Quit
        Call OpenAccessDatabase(strPath & ".accdb")

    End If

End Sub


Sub ADO_Connection_1()

    date1 = Format(Date, "DD")
    
    Year = Format(Date, "YYYY")
    
    Month = Format(Date, "MM")
    
    MonthChar = MonthName(Month, False)

    'Creating objects of Connection and Recordset
    Dim conn As New Connection, rec As New Recordset

    Dim DBPATH, PRVD, connString As String
    'Declaring fully qualified name of database. Change it with your database's location and name.
    DBPATH = "Z:\Danny Tool Test Folder\Database\" & Year & "\" & _
    Month & ". " & MonthChar & " " & Year & "\WeeklyActivity_" & date1 & Month & Year & _
    ".accdb"

    'This is the connection provider. Remember this for your interview.
    PRVD = "Microsoft.ace.OLEDB.12.0;"

    'This is the connection string that you will require when opening the connection.
    connString = "Provider=" & PRVD & "Data Source=" & DBPATH

    'opening the connection
    conn.Open connString

End Sub

'exports the data from the spreadsheet to the Access database
Sub ExportReport()

    'declaring our files, directories, tables and field names
    Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String, FileName As String
    Dim strTable As String
    Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean
    Dim MasterDB As Worksheet
    
    date1 = Format(Date, "DD")

    'Declaring year value of 1 month
    'This is important to compare datasets from last month
    If date1 > 26 Then
    Year_1M = Format(Date - 37, "YYYY")
    
    Else
    Year_1M = Format(Date - 27, "YYYY")
    
    End If

    'Declaring month value of 1 month
    'This is important to compare datasets from last month
    If date1 > 26 Then
    Month_1M = Format(Date - 37, "MM")
    
    Else
    Month_1M = Format(Date - 27, "MM")
    
    End If

    'This translates the current month from number to character format
    MonthChar_1 = MonthName(Month_1M, False)
    
    'setting Account sheet as MASTERFILE & the date
    sheet = "Overall Activity" & "!"
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    blnHasFieldNames = True
    
    strPath = "Z:\Danny Tool Test Folder\"
    
    strTable = "ActivityTable"
    
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "Weekly Activity Reporting Tool.xlsm")
      strPathFile = strPath & strFile
      DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
            strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames, sheet
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
End Sub

'function opens the Access database
Public Function OpenAccessDatabase(strPath As String)

    If Not IsNull(strPath) Then Shell "MSACCESS.EXE """ & strPath & """", vbNormalFocus
    
End Function
```

(It fails at *DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet*)

Comment: Please include the code you are using in your question.

Comment: Do you want to export the spreadsheet or import it? **DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport**

Comment: Code is in Access to create another Access file and import Excel data to that other file? Year and Month are intrinsic functions - I would not use them as variable names. Should use Option Explicit at top of module and explicitly declare all variables.

Comment: What is code for OpenAccessDatabase() procedure?

Comment: Yes I meant to say I'm looking for import spreadsheet to Access database. I have publicly declared these variables in a different module as I use them throughout the project - Option Explicit is included at the top of this module.

Comment: @June7 I have updated code to include this

Comment: Okay, so code is in EXCEL which creates an ACCESS file and attempts to import spreadsheet into that new db file. I have to ask - why is EXCEL used as data repository?

Comment: Still seems to be some code missing. The conn variable is local to procedure. CreateAccessDB creates and opens file which stays open and ExportReport fails because file is locked. Nothing in ExportReport procedure establishes Access object or connection.  Don't see how code works at all. Also, RangeToRecordset and ADO_Connection_1 procedures are not even called, why provide irrelevant code and omit relevant? I changed Year and Month to Yr and Mn.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the correct spreadsheet format:

```vb
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
    strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames, sheet
```

[AcSpreadSheetType enumeration (Access)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.acspreadsheettype?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361)

Comment: This code line is confirmed and verified here, so something else is going on. Double-check everything.

Answer (score 0):

This simple procedure creates database if doesn't already exist then transfers data from Excel to database.

```
Sub ExcelToAccess()
    Dim strDbPath As String
    Dim strExFile As String
    Dim strTable As String
    Dim Sht As String
    Dim objAccess As Object
    Dim date1 As String, Yr As String, Mn As String
    date1 = Format(Date, "DD")
    Yr = Format(Date, "YYYY")
    Mn = Format(Date, "MM")
    Sht = "Sheet1!"
    strTable = "Test"
    strExFile = "C:\Users\Owner\June\MyStuff\Condos.xlsm"
    strDbPath = "C:\Users\Owner\June\Forums\WeeklyActivity_" & date1 & Mn & Yr & ".accdb"

    Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    objAccess.Visible = False

    If Dir(strDbPath) = "" Then
        objAccess.NewCurrentDatabase(strDbPath)
    Else
        objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase (strDbPath)
    End If

    objAccess.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, strTable, strExFile, True, Sht
End Sub
```